# Getting 'Parse error: syntax error' while adding new Model named Return to ReturnController in Laravel 5.5.43

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an old Laravel project of Laravel Framework 5.5.43 , The models are there inside Model folder of app. I have created a model called Return inside that Model folder. But getting the following error while going to use that model in ReturnController, even in another.

This is the Return.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Return extends Model
{

}
```

And this is the ReturnController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Enums\OrderType;
se Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Order;
use App\Model\Return;
use App\Services\SellService;

class ReturnController extends Controller
{

}
```

The error is given below...

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Return' (T_RETURN), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or '{'

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Php thinks that it is `return` keyword. Just Change model name